# Xcode Enable UIFileSharing at Runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, file-sharing

is there a way to enable itunes UiFileSharing at runtime?
I need to start my application with UiFileSharing Disabled and Enable it under superuser configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible unfortunately, here's a similar question relating to changing the values of different settings in the info.plist file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1430351/879741

The best you could do I think is to not allow a non-registered user to look at and interact with the files being shared in-app.  Stopping a non-registered user from adding/removing files from iTunes wouldn't be possible.  File sharing is either off or on.

Comment: you're right. Apple developer has confirmed that is not possible. I hope it will be enabled in the future